# Постоянная функция

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! Как в JavaScript организовать функцию, которая будет исполняться все время, к примеру пока открыта страница? Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите setInterval и setTimeout. Наверно вы про это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте setInterval();

```
intervalId = window.setInterval(function () { console.log("1"); }, 1000);
```

Так же можно будет остановить выполнение функции убрав этот интервал window.clearInterval(intervalId); по идентификатору запущенного интервала, который возвращается функцией setInterval